# Anchor tag behavior on <tr> element in React

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I'm creating a React application with a component that looks something like this:

```
class TableRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const handleClick = () => window.location.href = "some-url";

        return (
            <tr>
                <td>Something 1</td>
                <td>Something 2</td>
                <td>Something 3</td>
                <td>Something 4</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

I want the <**tr**> tag to behave like an <**a**> tag, where you can:

1. click on it and have it go to "some-url"
2. command+click on it and have it go to "some-url" but in a new tab

Scenario 1 is simple since I can add an `onClick` property onto the <**tr**>, but when you try command+clicking on it, it doesn't open in a new tab.

I don't want to wrap the entire component within an <**a**> tag since React throws a warning saying that a <**tbody**> tag shouldn't have <**a**> tags as children. I also don't want to wrap all the <**td**> tags under one <**a**> tag since a similar warning is thrown.

Comment: **I also don't want to wrap all the <td> tags under one <a>**, how about adding `<a>` as child element of `<td>` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to do this either - the main reason is because I want to click anywhere within the <tr> and be able to go to the url.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried react, but I tried to solved your issue with just javascript.

Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLszr7b6/2/)

```
//delegate click events on the table
document.getElementById("table-with-anchors").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  //check if the targeted tr is set to be as an anchor
  if (e.target && e.target.parentElement.classList.contains("tr-as-anchor")) {
    //Do your stuffs here.
    window.open('', '_blank');
  }
  else {
    alert("You selected tr without anchor");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I found this post and it addresses exactly what I want to do: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/a2c54cc97a-cmdclick-a-link-open-in-a-new-tab-with-javascript

Essentially, as part of the `event` object thats passed to handleClick, I can determine whether the `metaKey` was used as well. And if it is, then I can open it in a new tab.